# How to pass current date value into the bottom count

Tags: excel, filter, ssas, mdx

I was trying to get a worst performing product group for a selected date, using bottom count. My aim is to return the amount and not the dimension name. But the query is returning the bottom count based on the default date in the cube and not form the select query. Is there a way to pass the current date into the bottomcount? Below is the sample query which i was using:

```
with
member worst as
([Measures].[Amount])

set worstgrp as
BOTTOMCOUNT([Product].[Product].Members ,1 , [Measures].[worst])

member worstamount as
sum([worstgrp],[Measures].[Amount])

select
{[worstamount]} on 0,
([date].[date].[month-day].[18 Jul 2014]) on 1

from
[Full Details]
```

We can have multi select on date. And to be exact I am trying to create a calculated member in the cube and use that cube for an ad hoc report usinfg excel. So I guess we cannot pu the date in where clause, but only in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your set as follows:

```
set worstgrp as BOTTOMCOUNT([Product].[Product].Members ,1 ,
                            sum(EXISTING [date].[date].Members, [Measures].[worst]))
```